# EF Migration fails due to GUID foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following models in my `.NET Core` 2.1 application:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }

}

public class Retailer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BusinessId {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }
}

public class Favourite
{

    [Key]
    public Guid FavouriteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Retailer_BusinessId")]
    public virtual Retailer Business { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product_ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

When trying to run an `EF` migration, I get the following error:

> The relationship from 'Favourite.Business' to 'Retailer.Favourites'
>   with foreign key properties {'Retailer_BusinessId' : Nullable}
>   cannot target the primary key {'BusinessId' : Guid} because it is not
>   compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign
>   key properties for this relationship.

I suspect it's because I'm using `Guid`'s as my keys in the foreign tables.  How do I tell `EF` that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like EF expects the `ForeignKey` attribute to refer to the navigation property.  I was able to reproduce the error you were getting and after making the following change, it migrated successfully.

```
public class Favourite
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FavouriteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Business")]
    public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Retailer Business { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** The way you were doing it was close, but you need to have the property and then specify just the property's name in the `ForeignKey` attribute.

```
public class Favourite
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FavouriteId { get; set; }

    public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessId")]
    public virtual Retailer Business { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```